# Doctrine 2, prevent getting unjoined entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

given a `user` and his `coupons`, I want to get a user and all of his coupons:

```
foreach ($this->createQueryBuilder('x')->select('u, c')->where('x.email = ?0')->setParameter(0, $email)->leftJoin('u.coupons', 'c')->getQuery()->getResult() as $entity)
{
    $entity->getCoupons();
}
```

this is very good until I forget to join the coupons:

```
foreach ($this->createQueryBuilder('x')->select('u')->where('x.email = ?0')->setParameter(0, $email)->getQuery()->getResult() as $entity)
{
    $entity->getCoupons();
}
```

sadly this still works even though no coupons were joined. Here it does an other SELECT. In additional, this 2nd select will be wrong. Id rather want to get a exception or AT LEAST an empty array instead. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're experiencing is expected doctrine behavior.

When you select a `User` entity, Doctrine will get the record from the database. If you aren't explicitly joining the `Coupon` entity (or any other entities with relationship to `User`), Doctrine will create a [Proxy](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/advanced-configuration.html#proxy-objects) object. Once you access this proxy object by calling `$user->getCoupons()`, Doctrine will fire a new query to the database to get the coupons for your `User` entity. This is called `lazy-loading`.

I'm not sure if there is a way to change this in the way you described.

What you can do is to create a method in your `UserRepository` called `findUserAndCoupons($email)` and have your query there. Whenever you need to find a user and his coupons, you could simply retrieve it in your controller using:

```
class MyController extends Controller {
    public function myAction(){
        $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('UserRepository')->findUserAndCoupons($email);

        foreach($user->getCoupons() as $coupon) {
            // ....
        }
    }

}
```

This way you won't need to remember the actual query and copy/paste it all over the place. :)